# Alert on Jquery on Mobile view

Tags: jquery, mobile

My code works fine in desktop / laptop
The problem is when i try viewing with mobile
No alert happen.

I try adjust click touchstart , click tap , click touch still nothing.
I try few solution on stackoverflow but nothing working with my answer

I dont think my code is wrong at all because is work fine in desktop view

HTML FORM

```
<div class="frm-button"><input type="submit" id="register-me" value="Register" /></div>
```

JQUERY CODE

```
jQuery('#register-me').on('click touchstart',function(){

var action = 'register_action';
     
var username = jQuery("#st-username").val();
var mail_id = jQuery("#st-email").val();
 var firname = jQuery("#st-fname").val();
 var lasname = jQuery("#st-lname").val();
 var passwrd = jQuery("#st-psw").val();  
    if (!username) {
    alert("Please Enter Username");
        return
    }    

     if (!mail_id) {
        alert("Please Enter Email");
         return
    }
     if (!isValidEmailAddress(mail_id)){
         alert("Please Enter Valid Email");
         return
     }
     if (!firname) {
        alert("Please Enter IC");
         return
     }
     if (firname.length<12||firname.length>12)  {
        alert("Please Enter Valid IC");
         return
     
     }
     if (!lasname) {
        alert("Please Enter Phone");
         return
    }
    
     if (!isANumber(lasname)){ 
    alert("Please Enter Valid No Phone");
         return
    }
         if (!passwrd) {
        alert("Please Enter Password");
             return
    }
     
     
     
 var url = "https://secure.astrataipan.com/apibsmmkl_uat/api/regnewtmpbsmm";
     console.log(username)
        console.log(mail_id)
        console.log(lasname)
        console.log(firname)
        console.log(passwrd)
 
var ajaxdata = {

action: 'register_action',
 name: username,
 email: mail_id,
 icno: firname,
 phoneno: lasname,
 password: passwrd,

};

jQuery.post( ajaxurl, ajaxdata, function(res){ // ajaxurl must be defined previously
console.log(res)
jQuery("#error-message").html(res);
 });
jQuery.post( url, ajaxdata, function(res){ // ajaxurl must be defined previously
console.log(res)
    if (res.Code=="888"){
        alert(res.Status);
    }
    else if (res.Code=="887"){
        alert(res.Status);
    }
    else if (res.Code=="200"){
        alert("Terima kasih kerana berminat di dalam program BSMMKL. Kami telah menerima permohonan anda dan kakitangan kami akan menghubungi anda dalam masa terdekat. !");
    }
    else {
        alert('Registration Error');
    }
jQuery("#error-message").html(res);
 });
     
     function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(
        /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i
    );

    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
}
     function isANumber(str){
  return !/\D/.test(str);
}
 });
```

Comment: Put your jquery code bottom of the page, then it will works on mobile.

Comment: Still not working. Did u need full code?

Comment: I need to refresh my cache and its working